# Timezone in laravel 5.5 not working

Tags: laravel-5, timezone

I changed my timezone in the  config/app.php file and set it to `'timezone' => 'Asia/Manila'`. I already did the `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` and still does not work. Please help.

This is the date i get:

```
January 24, 2018 7:42:am
```

What i want it to be:

```
January 23, 2018 3:45:pm
```

I am using `$date = Carbon::now();`to show the date

Comment: "still does not work" is very, very vague. Please be precise about what you expect to see vs what you do see.

Comment: @JonSkeet please see edited post

Comment: Now show the code you're using to display that date/time. Ideally in a [mcve], although not being a PHP or Laravel dev, I don't know exactly what that should look like. (I'm trying to help you improve your question so that someone who *does* know about Laravel will be able to help you.)

Comment: (If this is meant to be showing the current date/time, you should check that the system clock is correct, btw.)

Comment: If it was showing 7:42am on January 24th 6 hours ago, I suspect your system clock is incorrect. (It wasn't that time in *any* time zone.)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

in your Model or the Controller. This code sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script.

> This function returns FALSE if the timezone_identifier isn't valid, or
>   TRUE otherwise.